# What is the problem with kivymd.icon_definitions.md_icons in packaging?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've created an app with kivy and when I run it, it works properly. But as soon as I package it using pyinstaller, it fails. When I package it and click on the `.exe` file, I encounter the error below:

> unable to import package 'kivymd.icon_definitions.md_icons'

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and invested some time in finding a solution. Ultimately, I discovered that adding the following line to the imports section of my main script (main.py) resolved the problem:

```
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
```

After making this modification, I ran .spec file again. Surprisingly, this was the sole change needed to get my application to open successfully. While I can't provide a clear explanation for why this specific import resolved the issue, it proved to be an effective solution in my case.